# Text not showing up on illustrator file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I am a beginner to illustrator. I attempting to add text using the text tool. I am successful doing it in the practice file, but same actions don't work in my "live" file. Below images show my set up. Attribute/Overprint fill is not selected.

[image]

and these are the layers as I have them set up

[image: layers]

adding on to this, here is the text properties I have set:[image: font properties]

Comment: Does the text have a fill?

Comment: Do you own the font?

Answer (score 0):

Try to [reset your text type](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UA1Q-LzYZ6Y).

If that doesn't work, maybe try increasing the font size. Your text looks tiny in your first screenshot.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I tried to add more than one photo to my original post but it only allowed me to add one. Hence adding the photos in the answers. If there is a way to do it in the original post, thought, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Check your layer stack order, object stack order and opacity setting of the text object.

Answer (score 0):

Check your appearance attributes - Appearance Panel. Try it 1) with the text "object" selected  and if necessary 2) highlight the type and check again. Click "Clear Appearance".

Answer (score 0):

Try resizing the text box and adjusting the size of the font. It looks like the text is being written properly (the title of the layer is Loren Ipsum...). It also looks like the lines of text are being displayed by the light blue rectangles. Drag the bottom right corner of the box out to see if you can see the text.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. For me, it was that Illustrator didn't have the font that I was using even though it showed it was turned on. So just try a few different fonts or maybe redownload it.